# why the inverse of a circulant matrix is circulant?

Tags: circulant-matrices

Does any body know why the inverse of a circulant matrix is circulant? is there any reference or easy proof for that?

Comment: Do you know something about the eigenvectors of a circulant matrix?

Comment: yes I know the inverse is $YEY^{*}$ but how to proof its circulant?